# How to retrieve data of a single user from a list of many users

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having problem on retrieving data of a specific user when "View This Profile" button is pressed. I am building a recruitment web system in which I want employer to be able to view job seeker's profile when the view button is pressed.

Here is the sample code:

```
<?php
    $sqli_one= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT personal_info_tbl.Name, personal_info_tbl.Email, personal_info_tbl.Gender, personal_info_tbl.Career_objective, education_tbl.Career, education_tbl.Degree_University, registration_tbl.profile_picture, registration_tbl.Status);
 while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli_one, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $name = $rows['Name'];
        $gender = $rows['Gender'];
        $career = $rows['Career'];
        $career_objective = $rows['Career_objective'];
        $college = $rows['Degree_University'];
        $profile_picture = $rows['profile_picture'];
        $_SESSION['viewedEmail'] = $rows['Email'];
        $_SESSION['userPhoto'] = $rows['profile_picture'];
        $_SESSION['viewedName'] = $rows['Name'];
        
?>

    <div class="col-sm-4" style="height: 200px; border: 6px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 30px; background-color: #CCFFFF; margin-top: 5px;">
        <div class="row" style="height: 100px; max-width: auto; color: #0000FF; overflow: hidden;">
     <div class="col-sm-3" style="margin-top: 15px;">
         <?php echo "<img src='profile_pictures/".$rows['profile_picture']."' class='img-responsive' style='image-orientation:from-image;'>";?>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: right; font-weight: bolder;">Name:&nbsp</div>
            <div class="col-sm-8" style="text-align: left;"><?php echo "$name"; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: right; font-weight: bolder;">College:</div>
            <div class="col-sm-8" style="text-align: left;"><?php echo "$college"; ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: right; font-weight: bolder;">Gender:</div>
            <div class="col-sm-8" style="text-align: left;"><?php echo "$gender";  ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4" style="text-align: right; font-weight: bolder;">Career:&nbsp</div>
            <div class="col-sm-8" style="text-align: left;"><?php  echo "$career"; ?></div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div> 

    <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
        <div style="color: #d80000;"><h6><strong>Marked As:</strong>&nbsp<?php  echo $rows['Marked_As'];  ?></h6>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;">
    <?php echo "<a href='profile_page.php?Email='" . $_SESSION['viewedEmail'] . "'><button class='btn button'>View This Profile</button></a>"; ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Here is a sample output; when an employer clicks view this profile button, I want the specific clicked profile to appear with details of the selected job seeker's profile. Please help

Here is the code for **profile_page.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email'])) {

    $email = $_GET['email'];

    $sqli_one= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT personal_info_tbl.Email, personal_info_tbl.Name, personal_info_tbl.Gender, personal_info_tbl.Career_objective, personal_info_tbl.Nationality, personal_info_tbl.BOD, personal_info_tbl.Residence, personal_info_tbl.Skills, personal_info_tbl.Language, personal_info_tbl.Training, personal_info_tbl.Sport, personal_info_tbl.Mobile, personal_info_tbl.Country, personal_info_tbl.Address WHERE personal_info_tbl.Email = '".$email."'") or die("We could not execute your query sqli_one&nbsp".mysqli_error($connection));

   $rows = mysqli_fetch_array($sqli_one, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $cand_email = $rows['Email'];
   $cand_name = $rows['Name'];
   $cand_gender = $rows['Gender'];
   $cand_career_objective = $rows['Career_objective'];
   $cand_nationality = $rows['Nationality'];
   $cand_dob = $rows['BOD'];
   $cand_residence = $rows['Residence'];
   $cand_skills = $rows['Skills'];
   $cand_language = $rows['Language'];
   $cand_training = $rows['Training'];
   $cand_sports = $rows['Sport'];
   $cand_mobile = $rows['Mobile'];
   $cand_country = $rows['Country'];
   $cand_address = $rows['Address'];
}
?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 93px;">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;">
            <div class="row" style="background-color: #cccccc; color: #000;">
                <h3 style="text-align: center; font-variant-caps: uppercase; text-transform: uppercase;">
                <strong><?php echo $viewedName; ?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;CURRICULUM VITAE</strong></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="background-color: #3483cd; color: #ffffff;">
                <h3 style="text-align: center; font-variant-caps: uppercase; text-transform: uppercase;">
                <strong>Career Objective</strong></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="background-color: #cccccc; color: #000;">
                <h4 style="font-weight: bolder; text-align: center;"><?php echo "$cand_career_objective"; ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="background-color: #3483cd; color: #ffffff;">
                <h3 style="text-align: center; font-variant-caps: uppercase; text-transform: uppercase;">
                <strong>PERSONAL INFROMATION</strong></h3>
            </div>
                    <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
                        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: #cccccc; color: #000;">Name:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8"><?php echo "$cand_name"; ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
                        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: #cccccc; color: #000;">Gender:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8"><?php echo "$cand_gender"; ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
                        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: #cccccc; color: #000;">Nationality:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8"><?php echo "$cand_nationality"; ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
                        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: #cccccc; color: #000;">BIRTH DATE:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8"><?php echo "$cand_dob"; ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
                        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: #cccccc; color: #000;">RESIDENCE:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-8"><?php echo "$cand_residence"; ?></div>
                    </div>
            <div class="row" style="background-color: #3483cd; color: #ffffff;">
                <h3 style="text-align: center; font-variant-caps: uppercase; text-transform: uppercase;">
                <strong>CONATCT INFROMATION</strong></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: #cccccc; color: #000;">EMAIL:
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8"><?php echo "$cand_email"; ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: #cccccc; color: #000;">MOBILE:
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8"><?php echo "$cand_mobile"; ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: #cccccc; color: #000;">COUNTRY:
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8"><?php echo "$cand_country"; ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
                <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: #cccccc; color: #000;">ADDRESS:
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8"><?php echo "$cand_address"; ?></div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the specific problem you have? Have you already checked [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that you need to do is to remove the `$_SESSION['viewedEmail']` on the query string because this will not give you the required results on the `profile_page` this will always give you the same value all the time until you destroy the session.

Therefore this :

```
<?php echo "<a href='profile_page.php?Email='" . $_SESSION['viewedEmail'] . "'><button class='btn button'>View This Profile</button></a>"; ?>
```

Should change to this :

```
<?php echo "<a  class='btn button' href='profile_page.php?email='" . $row['Email'] . "'>View This Profile</a>"; ?>
```

Then to get the details of the clicked profile then you do this:

**profile_page.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email'])){


        $email = $_GET['email'];


        //THEN SELECT WHAT YOU NEED FROM TABLE WHERE EMAIL = $email
    }else{

        //THE PERSON IS VIEWEING THE PAGE ILLEGAL DO SOMETHING
    }
```

Comment: I did every thing you said but its not working, all of my php variable in profile_page.php shows undefined variables error

Comment: you need to show me the code in profile_page.php @JimmyMchau I'm sure the error is not caused by my code

Comment: thanks for your reply, i edit my questions to add the codes for profile_page.php, you can refresh the page to see the added codes

Comment: what errors are you getting @JimmyMchau the above does answer what you asked initially you should mark it then open a new thread for new questions

Comment: am getting "Undefined variables errors" @MasivuyeCokile
Notice: Undefined variable: cand_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\EmploymentVan\profile_page.php on line 182Notice: Undefined variable: cand_gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\EmploymentVan\profile_page.php on line 187Notice: Undefined variable: cand_nationality in C:\xampp\htdocs\EmploymentVan\profile_page.php on line 192Notice: Undefined variable: cand_dob in C:\xampp\htdocs\EmploymentVan\profile_page.php on line 197

Comment: that is  new thread u will need to open a new question for that, as your orginal question was answerd

Comment: Thanks friend @Masivuye Cokile

Answer (score 0):

Since you are linking `View this profile` button to a different page (`profile_page.php?Email=`) you should make a separate query in `profile_page.php` where you select a specific user based on passed `viewedEmail` variable.